# Writing Error Messages For Shiny UI With validate()

Tags: r, shiny

I would like to create a Shiny UI with 3 checkboxes for the user to choose from. However, I want to prompt the user with an error message if none of the boxes are selected.

I have tried using the validate function to solve this (as shown below) but it's currently not working. Can anyone point out what's wrong with my code and show me how to resolve it?

```
shinyUI(fluidPage(sidebarLayout(
  sidebarPanel(checkboxGroupInput(
    "variable", "Select An Option:",
    c(
      "One",
      "Two",
      "Three"
    )
  )),

  mainPanel(textOutput("text"))
)))

shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  text.data <- reactive({
    validate(need(!is.null(input$variable),
  "Please select an option"))
    print(input$variable)
  })
  output$text <- renderPrint({
    print(text.data())
  })
})
```

**EDIT**

I have included images of the results I'm getting below:

- When nothing is selected, the message displayed in "NULL NULL" instead of "Please select an option"

[image]

- When a box is selected, this error message is displayed: "Error:is.character(txt) is not TRUE" instead of the a print out of the input selected.

[image]

Comment: seems to work fine, the message is displayed when none of the boxes are ticked

Comment: Really, did you get "NULL NULL" as well or "Please select an option"? I've included images of what I'm getting.

Comment: no I didnt get the NULL NULL, but instead the expected message when no boxes are ticked.  You are getting it twice because of the extra `print` in the `renderPrint`.  but, aside from that, are you up-to-date with packages?

Comment: You're absolutely right, I updated my packages and it now works - thanks Bunk!

Answer (score 28):

For others benefit, package problems are a common error with the `validate()` function due to the presence of naming collisions or masking (because it's such a common function name). For example, if you're using the qdap or jsonlite packages then calling `validate()` might not be calling the shiny version of the function.

To test if this is your issue, try replacing `validate()` with `shiny::validate()` or changing the order you load your libraries.

Comment: C W you are a hero! `jsonlite` was the problem. Others stuck with this - In Rstudio type out `validate` in your console, but do not press enter. Rstudio will show a hover box above the command, and this helps you identify what package your command is defaulting to.

Comment: Great, it works with shiny::validate(), thanks a lot